# I am in the beginning of time and space - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am in the beginning of time and space. I stand for nothing, but I mean a lot. I cannot be divided into parts. What am I?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd guess you are:

> 0 - zero

I am in the beginning of time and space.

> Depending on your date/time format, you might have leading zeros on hours, minutes, and seconds. Some spacial coordinates and many distance counters use leading zeros. A simple example is the mileage counter on a vehicle. Geo-spacial coordinates for latitude and longitude on Earth often, but not always, include leading zeros.

I stand for nothing, but I mean a lot.

> A zero literally means a lack of everything, but if you string zeros behind another number, it can mean quite a lot. Example: 0 and 100000000.  Also, zero is essentially what all other numbers are compared against, so that gives it significant meaning.

I cannot be divided into parts.

> Zero can't be divided, since nothing can't be subdivided into smaller parts of nothing.

Comment: Correct! This was my intended answer, but Gareth's answer is equally valid.

Comment: I can easily divide 0 dollar among 8 people. Everyone will get 0 dollar. Mathmatically zero can be divide without issues.

Comment: @StefanJanssen I agree with this logic.

Comment: The other way around is not mathematical solvable ... divide by zero

Comment: @StefanJanssen, while that's true, everyone gets the same amount of 0 dollars, which is equal to the original number, so that's not dividing 0, it's still just zero.

Comment: @StefanJanssen Is the 0 dollars you got from that division equal to 1/8th of the 0 that you started with?  If not, you're not "dividing it into parts"; you're essentially showing that there are no parts to be divided.

Comment: @Jmac yes, that 0 dollars is 1/8 of the original 0 dollars.  That's how 0 works.

Comment: @Hoog You could say it's 1/8th of the original 0 dollars, but by that logic you could also say it's 100/8th's of the original 0 dollars; both are mathematically correct.  It doesn't mean the nothing was divided into parts; it means that attempts to divide nothing into parts still leaves nothing; not a partial nothing.

Comment: Saying you can't divide 0 is like saying you can't add 0 or multiply by 1. All are legal operations that do a whole lot of nothing. What you can't do is divide by 0 without blowing a hole in your system of algebra. When faced with `x/y = z` it's the `y` you need to know about before you can trust it isn't going to blow up on you. Not the `x`. The question needs an edit because as written the correct answer is undefined.

Comment: You could interpret "I mean a lot" as referring to the *mean* of the standard normal distribution (which is 0), which arises *a lot* for those interested in means.

Answer (score 31):

Perhaps you are

> a POINT.

I am in the beginning of time and space

> Slight misunderstanding of the "big bang" here, but it's commonly thought of as starting with all the mass/energy of the universe compressed infinitely small, into a single point.

I stand for nothing

> Perhaps thinking of a decimal point, which (unlike the digits nearby) doesn't itself contribute anything to the value of the number it helps to represent.

but I mean a lot

> "Right, now let's get to the point."

I cannot be divided into parts.

> This was even Euclid's *definition* of "point", back when he wrote the world's first geometry textbook.

Comment: Equally valid answer, but not what I intended.

Comment: I was *positive* this was the right answer - exactly what went through my mind on first seeing this puzzle...

Comment: Not sure about the "contribute [...] value" bit...?

Comment: Ahh, the old "Good answer but not what I was thinking" from OP.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> The God of Classical Theism

I stand for nothing

> According to Classical Theism, God is impassible, that is, God has no passions. People stand for what they are passionate about. God has no passions.

I mean a lot

> The significance of God is once again found in a particular doctrine of Classical Theism: Aseity. God is the first and self-sufficient being, needing no other, existing in and of himself.

I cannot be divided into parts:

> This is the definition of another important facet of Classical Theism: Simplicity. God is simple, not a composite being. He cannot be divided into parts.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are

> Dark Matter.

In the beginning of time and space

> Dark matter is all there was and is at the outer edge of space. It was there at the start of time and space had yet to be formed.

I stand for nothing, but mean a lot

> Dark matter does not have a stance in many things we interact with, but it means a lot to the reasoning of space and time

I cannot be divided into parts

> It is already in its final form!

Answer (score 2):

You are

> ZERO (0)

In the beginning of time and space.

> Everything starting point from Zero (0)

I stand for nothing, but I mean a lot.

> Yes, If any number after zero less value and number after zero means a lot. example: 00000001 and 10000000

I cannot be divided into parts

> ZERO can't be divide in to parts, because it means void or null.

Answer (score 1):

## What am I?

> The emptiness of the universe.

#### I am in the beginning of time and space.

> It was always there, despite the matter of the big bang, which was literally a single point on the vast emptiness.

#### I stand for nothing, but I mean a lot.

> Emptiness, is nothing, just vaccum, not a single molecule. But means a lot, because it's considered to be infinite.

#### I cannot be divided into parts.

> You can't divide "nothing".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange in the future try to use spoiler markers >! before your solutions and explanations in case people want to solve the puzzle on their own.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Null

I am in the beginning of time and space

> Time is a function of state-change that progresses relative to E in the inertial frame(s) in which it is observed. When the universe was initialized to Null, E=0 T=0

I stand for nothing, but I mean a lot

> Null means initialized... with no value

I cannot be divided into parts.

> Divide with Null... get error: Divide by zero error encountered

Answer (score 0):

What about

> [The Infinity Gaunlet](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet)?

I am in the beginning of time and space

> Time Stone and Space Stone need the Infinity Gaunlet to be used together.

I stand for nothing, but I mean a lot

> The Gaunlet itself does nothing, but using the Infinity stones it can become the most powerful weapon in the universe.

I cannot be divided into parts.

> Infinity Gaunlet is made from one of the toughest materials in the universe.