# The dimensional Portal

Tags: riddle

What am I? I am like a portal between two worlds, where neither one of them is our world. The second world is mirrored to the first one, but I am not a mirror.

Hint

> The "Portal" exists in our world, but it's not connected to our world.

Hint 2

> The meaning of "Portal" is not literal

Comment: The closest alternative would be a water surface but still seems too simple.

Comment: Well, it's wrong :p

Comment: rot13(Vg ybbxf yvxr Argure cbegny sebz Zvarpensg).

Comment: @trolley813 I had thought of a very similar thing from a different fictional source. Just to clarify, OP, is it a real world object?

Comment: What do you mean with "Real World"? It exists in our world, but not as that "World" . Also the Nether is not a mirrored version of the overworld. And the Portal is not literally a portal. I edided the riddle, maybe now it's more understandable

Comment: It's unfortunate that you happened to post this shortly after (SPOILER WARNING) [another riddle with exactly the same answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92963/i-am-in-the-beginning-of-time-and-space-what-am-i) - only a matter of hours in fact. Perhaps it would have fared better in the vote stakes on another day... Bad luck...

Comment: It's my first riddle. Is it at least a good one?

Comment: I think I would describe it as 'under-specified' - probably needed another line with another angle to help solvers pinpoint the answer more precisely. When multiple answers are given that each seem valid (e.g. the more 'visual' two below) it's usually a sign that you need more content (*useful* content, that is - not just filler) to help us nail down the answer with a satisfying "Ah, that *must* be it!" Take a read of some of the highest-voted riddles on this site to see what usually goes down well here. And most importantly, don't be discouraged - read, learn, try again and keep puzzling! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> Zero

Explanation:

> The two worlds may refer to the ordered sequences of positive numbers and negative numbers. As zero lies in the middle, it may be perceived as a portal. Considering the order of the sequences, the negative numbers may be considered as a “mirrored” image of positive numbers. Zero is not a tangible location in the real world; it is a number.

Comment: That's correct ^^

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> the eye

where the first world is :

> the world we see

and the second one :

> the image printed on the retina

like this

> [image]

Comment: In this case, the "gate" could be rot13(gur vevf, juvpu bcraf naq pybfrf yvxr n tngr)

Comment: That's kinda the same answer as the "Camera", which was also wrong, but still good guess

Comment: @Sneftel yes I think that could be it

Answer (score 1):

> A camera?

Because

> When you take a picture it's a mirrored version of our world.Not sure how it could look like a gate though.

Comment: Good guess, but wrong ^^

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn Answers to riddles aren't "wrong" just because they don't match the answer you were thinking of. If something isn't right, explain how it doesn't satisfy the riddle itself (and note that hints aren't part of the riddle). If it *does* satisfy the riddle, it's a correct answer, even if it's not the answer you were thinking of.

Comment: Well then, "Good guess, but not the answer I'm looking for". The Camera makes an image of our world, while in the riddle, it says neither one of the two worlds is our world

Answer (score 1):

Either

> x and y coordinates on a graph,

or similarly

> positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Oooh, that's quite close to what I thought

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! In general with answers try to add explanation to back up your thoughts and try to add spoiler bars (done by writing >! before your answer) so that people wont accidentally be spoiled for an answer

Comment: and what is the "portal" then?

Comment: What do you think it is

Comment: @Zzzz DudeWhoWantsToLearn is the author of the puzzle. He already knows what the "portal" is, he's asking whether you know what it is. If you do, that would be a strong indication that your answer is correct.